# Is there an easy way to get the content from a <pre> tag to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, html, dataframe, web-scraping, pre

I've trying to pass the content of a pre tag to a pandas dataframe but i've not been able to, this is what i have so far:

```
import requests,pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#url

url='http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=samer&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR=2019&MONTH=09&FROM=2712&TO=2712&STNM=80222'
peticion=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(peticion.content,"html.parser")

#get only the pre content I want

all=soup.select("pre")[0]

#write the content in a text file

with open('sound','w') as f:
    f.write(all.text)

#read it 
df = pandas.read_csv('sound')
df
```

I'm getting a not structured dataframe and since I have to do this with several urls I would rather to pass the data directly after the line 12 without the need of writing a file.

[this is the dataframe I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otr3l.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fixed width text so you need to generate the lines by splitting on '\n' and then the columns by using a fixed width value. You could use csv to save on overhead but you wanted a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=samer&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR=2019&MONTH=09&FROM=2712&TO=2712&STNM=80222')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
pre = soup.select_one('pre').text
results = []

for line in pre.split('\n')[1:-1]:
    if '--' not in line:
        row = [line[i:i+7].strip() for i in range(0, len(line), 7)]
        results.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
```