# Python cannot get table from stock exchange report

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

My code:

```
import time    
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/stat/dmstat/dayrpt/hsitmc220303.htm"

req = requests.get(URL)    
page = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')    
table = page.find_all('pre')    
df = pd.read_html(str(table), displayed_only=False)[0]    
print(df)
```

Error message:

```
ValueError: No tables found
```

I want to get the table to dataframe. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this work for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/58144946/6361531?

Comment: in that page table is not in html table format. its full of string arranged in the format of text. after loading the string into your system, you need to do some string processing to extract the content from the table and create a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/stat/dmstat/dayrpt/hsitmc220303.htm'

payload = {
'LangCode': 'en',
'TDD': '1',
'TMM': '11',
'TYYYY': '2019'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for row in jsonData['data']:
    #row = jsonData['data'][1]

    data_row = []
    for idx, colspan in enumerate(row['colspan']):
        colspan_int = int(colspan[0])
        data_row.append(row['td'][idx] * colspan_int)
        flat_list = [item for sublist in data_row for item in sublist]
    temp_row = pd.DataFrame([flat_list])
    final_df = final_df.append(temp_row, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)


df = final_df[final_df[0].str.contains(r'Total market 
capitalisation(?!$)')].iloc[:,:2]
df['date'] = date
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable